# Java client to C# server TCP

Tags: java, c#, tcp

The problem is when i send up to 40 KB everything is okay when i send more sometime half of the data received some time nothing ,is there a limit of the networkstream.Read ,even though i cunked the data ,i can't determine if the problem form the java or the c# from the network stream or the Output stream

**C# SERVER**

```
private void ReadData(){

                                    if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                                    {

                                        int size = GetBufferSize();
                                        Thread.Sleep(340);
                                        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[size];

                                        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;


                                        while (true)
                                        {
                                            numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

                                            if (numberOfBytesRead >= myReadBuffer.Length)
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, size);


                                        dynamic Message = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
                                        // Android Message , JSON String
                                        if (OnAndroidMessage != null)
                                        {
                                            OnAndroidMessage(Message);
                                        }

                                    }
}
  private int GetBufferSize()
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[4];
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        } while (networkStream.DataAvailable && numberOfBytesRead < myReadBuffer.Length);
        if (numberOfBytesRead > 0)
        {
            // reverse the byte array.
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(myReadBuffer);
            }

            return BitConverter.ToInt32(myReadBuffer, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**Java Client** // i tested this  also without cutting the data to smaller paces ,half of the data received not all of them

```
        mBufferOut = socket.getOutputStream();

private void sendMessage(final String message) {

    if (mBufferOut != null && message != null) {
        try {
            byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
            Log.d("_TAG", "Sending: " + message);
            Log.d("_TAG", "Message length: " + Integer.toString(data.length));

            mBufferOut.write(toByteArray(data.length));
            mBufferOut.flush();
            List<byte[]> divideArray = divideArray(data, 10000);
            for (byte[] dataChunk : divideArray) {
                Log.e("_TAG","CHUNK SIZE > " + Integer.toString(dataChunk.length));
                mBufferOut.write(dataChunk, 0, dataChunk.length);
                mBufferOut.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
  private  List<byte[]> divideArray(byte[] source, int chunksize) {

        List<byte[]> result = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        int start = 0;
        while (start < source.length) {
            int end = Math.min(source.length, start + chunksize);
            result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(source, start, end));
            start += chunksize;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: At least your reading code is invalid. It’s always trying to read a full buffer, from the start, and if it doesn’t it’ll just try again overwriting the buffer instead of continuing from where it left off. Might not be the issue, but can cause problems.

Comment: id don't get what you mean ,how im read buffer invalid or where ?

Comment: There’s not many places where you read the stream. Your code says “read this much to the start of the buffer”, then checks if it actually read that much. If it didn’t, it says the exact same thing, which overwrites what you already read and expects again to get the whole amount of data. And again and again possibly, if the stream is allowed to return incomplete data. If it isn’t the whole loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from this post [NetworkStream is reading data that should not be there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459880/networkstream-is-reading-data-that-should-not-be-there)

```
static void ReadExact(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int read;
    while(count > 0 && (read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0) {
        offset += read;
        count -= read;
    }
    if(count != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
```

the  problem is the Read it takes size and want to get  that  size you need to give it chunks  and check each chunk
And also  read does not restart from where it stopped until it reads the amount is set to read meaning if i set to read 10 then if it not find the 10 then  it  will read what it  find as example it reads 6 ,it will return 6 and when to loop another time ti read the rest it dose not start from 6 it start from 0 and read until 4 so you overwrite  your data  ,and if it read 10 from the first try then it  set the read to finish so it dose not start from 0 ,it needs to read the amount the  has been set to it to re set the read to new buffer location.